# Identification of 'event' in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events

The following markup works pretty well in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing Events</title>
<script>
function HandleInput() {
console.log(event.which);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label id="lblName">Please Enter You Name:</label>
<input id="txtName" type="text" onkeypress="HandleInput()"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Running this in Firefox leads to the following error message in the console:

> ReferenceError: event is not defined.

I do know the  solution to this; passing the event object in the function call.

But I would like to know why is it that this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because `window.event` is a nonstandard IE-ism which some other browsers copied but Firefox did not.  And the code you show is depending on there being an `event` property on the global, which means on the window.